# Execute one Maven plugin goal as the last

Tags: maven

I would like to run one Maven plugin goal ([jacoco:dump](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/dump-mojo.html)) at every Maven build of my project, no matter the phase of the build, and it should be the last goal executed.

One idea I would implement is link the jacoco:dump goal to the compile phase, in order to execute it at every build, but then it would be not possible to execute the dump as the last goal of the last phase.

Execution order

```
validate -> compile -> (any other phase and plugin goal execution) -> jacoco:dump
```

So if I build with `mvn verify`, `jacoco:dump` could be executed after the verify phase; if I build with `mvn compile` the `jacoco:dump` could be executed after the compile phase etc.

Is there any way to solve this problem with Maven?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple but effective. We can run the plugin goal directly from command line without configuring it into the project pom. 
As stated in the [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Build_Lifecycle_Basics), when running multiple goals from command line they are executed in the given order, so I only have to put the jacoco plugin at the tail of the command:

```
mvn compile org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.7.201606060606:dump sonar:sonar
```

The example above first compiles, then executes `jacoco:dump`, then executes `sonar:sonar`

Answer (score 2):

One (hacky) approach would be to pass the phase as a property each time. Something like:

```
 <execution>
    <id>jacoco</id>
    <phase>${phase}</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>dump</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
```

The call with `mvn compile -Dphase=compile` or `mvn test -Dphase=test` etc. Probably not the most elegant solution but pretty easy to implement.

Comment: Thank you. And what do you think if I use directly the plugin goal? Like `mvn test jacoco:dump`. As stated [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Build_Lifecycle_Basics), the execution order is the one given in the command line, so if I run `jacoco:dump` after all the wanted phases maybe I have the solution. What do you think?

Comment: Yes that sounds better!